# Knit does not work and has no response when I compile default document to pdf even if I updated latest packages

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

There is no response when I knit the default R markdown document to pdf, word or html. I basically got a **black box** and **nothing is running** and **received no error message** when I click Knit (`Ctrl + Shift + K`).

[image: Screenshot attachment can be found here]

I used a university desktop so I am not sure if this is due to an admin issue that blocks me from accessing some packages - my R script works fine and I can run code within R markdown. I just can't knit nor obtaining any error message.

I followed advice from Yihui Xie's Knit [FAQ](https://yihui.name/knitr/faq/) and updated all packages, restarted and reinstalled R studio and tried `devtools::install_version("rmarkdown", version = "1.8", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")`

The `sessionInfo()` is such that

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.3 (2019-03-11)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 16299)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Australia.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Australia.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_Australia.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                      
[5] LC_TIME=English_Australia.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] markdown_0.9 knitr_1.23  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.1        magrittr_1.5      usethis_1.5.0     devtools_2.0.2   
 [5] pkgload_1.0.2     R6_2.4.0          rlang_0.3.4       tools_3.5.3      
 [9] pkgbuild_1.0.3    xfun_0.7          sessioninfo_1.1.1 cli_1.1.0        
[13] withr_2.1.2       htmltools_0.3.6   remotes_2.0.4     yaml_2.2.0       
[17] assertthat_0.2.1  digest_0.6.19     rprojroot_1.3-2   crayon_1.3.4     
[21] processx_3.3.1    callr_3.2.0       fs_1.3.1          ps_1.3.0         
[25] testthat_2.1.1    glue_1.3.1        memoise_1.1.0     evaluate_0.14    
[29] rmarkdown_1.13    compiler_3.5.3    desc_1.2.0        backports_1.1.4  
[33] prettyunits_1.0.2
```

Could anyone advise what I should do regarding this issue? Thank you very much in advance.

**Updates: 7/06/2019:** 
I have latex installed in my computer and used Yihui Xie's `tinytex::install_tinytex()`, and obtained the following messages. The problems still persist - when I knit (Ctrl+Shift+K), nothing happened, no error message, no pdf, nothing at all.

```
> tinytex::install_tinytex()
MiKTeX-pdfTeX 2.9.6499 (1.40.18) (MiKTeX 2.9.6500 64-bit)
Copyright (C) 1982 D. E. Knuth, (C) 1996-2016 Han The Thanh
TeX is a trademark of the American Mathematical Society.
using bzip2 version 1.0.6, 6-Sept-2010
compiled with curl version 7.56.1; using libcurl/7.56.1 WinSSL
compiled with expat version 2.2; using expat_2.2.0
compiled with jpeg version 9.2
compiled with liblzma version 50020032; using 50020032
compiled with libpng version 1.6.34; using 1.6.34
compiled with libressl version LibreSSL 2.5.3; using LibreSSL 2.5.3
compiled with MiKTeX Application Framework version 2.6416; using 2.6416
compiled with MiKTeX Core version 3.6505; using 3.6516
compiled with MiKTeX Archive Extractor version 1.6300; using 1.6300
compiled with MiKTeX Package Manager version 1.6488; using 1.6488
compiled with poppler version 0.60.1
compiled with uriparser version 0.8.4
compiled with zlib version 1.2.11; using 1.2.11
trying URL 'http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/install-tl.zip'
Content length 359 bytes
downloaded 21.5 MB

trying URL 'https://yihui.name/gh/tinytex/tools/pkgs-custom.txt'
Content length 81 bytes
downloaded 318 bytes

trying URL 'https://yihui.name/gh/tinytex/tools/tinytex.profile'
Content length 81 bytes
downloaded 295 bytes

Error in setwd(dir) : character argument expected
In addition: Warning messages:
1: Detected an existing LaTeX distribution (e.g., pdftex is at C:\PROGRA~1\MIKTEX~1.9\miktex\bin\x64\pdftex.exe). You are recommended to uninstall it, although TinyTeX should work well alongside another LaTeX distribution if a LaTeX document is compiled through tinytex::latexmk(). 
2: In unzip("install-tl.zip") : error 1 in extracting from zip file
Please quit and reopen your R session and IDE (if you are using one, such as RStudio or Emacs) and check if tinytex:::is_tinytex() is TRUE.
```

**2nd Updates 8/06/2019**:
After reinstalling R language version 3.5.3 (I can't use version 3.6 at this moment due to University software management policy) and trying `devtools::install_github('rstudio/rmarkdown')` and `update.packages()`, I can knitr but received the following error messages:

```
"C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS tte.utf8.md --to latex --
from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash 
--output tte.tex --template "C:\R\R-3.5.2\library\rmarkdown\rmd\latex\default-1.17.0.2.tex" 
--highlight-style tango --pdf-engine pdflatex --variable graphics=yes --variable "geometry:margin=1in" 
--variable "compact-title:yes" 
pandoc.exe: tte.utf8.md: openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 1
Execution halted
```

I then tried to uninstall pandoc using `brew remove pandoc` but received this message:

```
> brew remove pandoc
Error: unexpected symbol in "brew remove"
```

Thank you, everyone, for advising my problem on using Rmarkdown but, unfortunately, the problem still exists.

Comment: To troubleshoot, try to knit manually using `knitr::knit` to turn your `Rmd` into a `md` file. If that works, try to render the pdf using `rmarkdown::render`.

Comment: Hi Antonie, Thank you for your reply. I tried `knitr::knit` and `rmarkdown::render` in the Console. The problem persists.

Comment: Please expand a bit - what happened when you knitted your file? It is ok to edit your question to add more details.

Comment: @LamontYu Could you show the version of RStudio on the computer you use? Have you verified that any latex system has already been installed on the computer?

Comment: Hi Antoine, the weird thing is nothing happened, no error message, no pdf, nothing, even though R studio is running.

Comment: Hi Carlos, Thank you for your reply. I have MikeTex installed. RStudio is version 1.2.1335 and R is version 3.5.3. I can use TexStudio to write document. No problem. I just got nothing when knitting to pdf, but I am sure I can use R markdown without problems couple months ago. Not sure what have happened.

Comment: Probably not a bad idea to update R to the latest version (3.6.0) and make sure all your packages are up to date as well.

Comment: @joshpk Hi Joshpk, I cant install 3.6 version at this moment but I reinstalled version R 3.53. I can knitr now but received messages (I updated details in the original post ). Thank you very much for help.